# Is there a solid block that doesn't suffocate entities in direwolf20 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-direwolf20

Is there a solid block that doesn't suffocate entities in direwolf20 1.7.10? I want to make a secret room using drawbridges!

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked up the direwolf20 mod? You can look at the wiki which has a list of all the mods installed in the direwolf20 pack. But other than that, in vanilla minecraft, I'm pretty sure there is no item that is a solid block that also doesn't suffocate entities. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

By solid block do you mean a block which you cannot pass through? If so, vanilla glass matches your qualifications. Or do you mean a block which you also cannot see through? If so, chests may or not work for your circumstance. The Secret Camo Chest from the Secret Rooms mod is in FTB, which contains most if not all mods from direwolf20, although it is not in direwolf20.

EDIT: Leaves from vanilla also work.